# Interceptors - how to create HTTP Handler for Apache / Tomcat?

Tags: apache, http, tomcat7, handler

I am looking example of http handler for apache tomcat 7.
I want to add check of user authority in case is ok redirect the request to the data server, if no authority return error - no permissions.

[image: usage of http handler with checking authorization of the user]

Comment: if somebody make -1 for the question, so be cool and edit it or answer it ! looser !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this documentation:
http://tomcatbook.sourceforge.net/book/defaulthtml/ch04.html
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html
hope it will be useful !